# Does $W_{out}$ in gas turbines refer to the shaft or the blades?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, heat-engine, carnot-cycle

I was studying the Bryton cycle for a gas turbine and a question came to my mind about the turbine work output. That is, are we talking about the work output for the turbine blades or about the work output for the shaft connected with these blades?

Comment: it's the same .

Comment: It's called "shaft work" for a reason.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, note that the turbine shaft is attached to a pump, electric generator, etc., to do work on those devices.